# Wait for multiple running threads via waitconditions

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, synchronization

i have a problem synchronizing multiple threads with qt (unfortunately 3.3.8). Because starting a thread is a time consuming task, i want to start a (worker)thread once, keep it in its run-method and inform it about new work. But i also need to synchronize those worker threads in the calling thread, when all work is done.

I know that the overloading of QThread is not the correct use of it, but in Qt 3.3.8 there is no moveToThread-Method and so i have to do this.

The worker-thread-class is defined as follows (simplified)

```
class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
  private:
    QWaitCondition m_wcNewWork;
    QMutex m_mutexStopped;
    bool m_bStopped; /// Stop thread execution

    void run()
    {
        m_mutexStopped.lock();
        while(!m_bStopped)
        {
            m_mutexStopped.unlock();    
            m_wcNewWork.wait(); //wait for new work

            msleep(1000); // do something

            //>notify main thread that the work is done<

            m_mutexStopped.lock();
        }
        m_mutexStopped.unlock();    
    }
  public:
    WorkerThread() : m_bStopped(false) {}
    ~WorkerThread()
    {
        m_mutexStopped.lock();  
        m_bStopped = true;
        m_mutexStopped.unlock();    
        wait(); // Wait for thread

        //Cleanup       
    }
    void startProcessing()
    {
        m_wcNewWork.wakeOne(); /// Wakeup thread, since there is something to do        
    }        
}
```

A bunch of those worker threads is created in another thread. Let's call this one *MainThread*.
Now i need something to inform the MainThread that all worker threads are done working. I thought WaitConditions in the MainThread would be a possibility to solve the problem, one for every WorkerThread. Then in the MainThread i wrote something like

```
QWaitCondition waitWorkDone[numWorker];

//Start working
for (int i = 0; i < numWorker; i++)
{
    WorkerThread[i].setWaitCondition(waitWorkDone);
    WorkerThread[i].startProcessing();
}

//Wait for all workers to finish their work
for (int i = 0; i < numWorker; i++)
{
    waitWorkDone[i].wait();
}
```

In the WorkerThread::run-method i used a `waitWorkDone.wakeOne()` to inform the MainThread that the work is done. Unfortunately this doesn't work. When the waitWorkDone is woken up before the wait, the MainThread waits forever.

So the question is: How can i synchronize threads, that are not leaving their run-method? I think in Qt 4 i could use threadpools to do this, but they don't exist in Qt 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are using your conditional variables (QWaitCondition) in a wrong way. They require using them with mutex to work right, or else wake... calls could be lost, like here.
You can either fix them, or (easier way) just use semaphore to wait for workers; worker threads increment it one time each, main thread decrements it numWorker times.

You can look for better explanations about conditional variables in "PThread Primer" book (very good introduction to multithreading, though somewhat out-of-date)

Comment: Thanks for the book-hint. I'll have a look at it. I also had the idea about the mutex in the waitcondition::wait-method but i am confused about that. If the mutex is mandatory, what is the purpose of the wait without the mutex?

Comment: Conditional variable and corresponding mutex are supposed to work together. Mutex is supposed to be locked when nobody is waiting for corresponding conditional variable (that's why wait... functions accept mutex), and when you call wake on conditional variable that nobody waits for it could be lost (which actually happens).